# Proving $f=\alpha g$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ if $f,g$ are homogeneous functions of degree $m,n$ respectively and $h=f+g$, $xh_{x}+yh_{y}=0$

Tags: solution-verification, homogeneous-equation

> I am supposed to prove that if $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are homogeneous functions of degree $m$ and $n$ respectively and that $h=f+g$, such that $xh_{x}+yh_{y}=0$, then for some scalar $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $f=\alpha g$.

Here is what I've tried so far. I've made use of Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions to write the following equations, from which I deduce that $f+g$ is also a homogeneous function of degree either $m$ or $n$, so clearly, whatever the function, $g$ it has to be a scalar multiple of $f$ and vice-versa. Is this reasoning correct and formal? Any inputs are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I gather from the context that you considering functions of two variables $x$ and $y.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, I forgot to mention that. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll make the necessary edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $u(x,y)$ we have
$${d\over dt}u(tx,ty)\Big |_{t=1}= [x\,u_x(tx,ty)+y\,u(tx,ty)]\Big |_{t=1}=xu_x+yu_y$$
Moreover, if $u$ is homogeneous of degree $k,$ then
$${d\over dt}u(tx,ty)\Big |_{t=1}={d\over dt}t^k\Big |_{t=1}\ u(x,y)=k\,u(x,y)$$
i.e. $xu_x+yu_y=ku.$

The assumptions imply
$$0=xh_x+yh_y=[xf_x+yf_y]+[xg_x+yg_y]=mf+ng.$$